# ArgoUML and calling a "sub-procedure"

Tags: uml, argouml

I don't know if its a limitation of UML 1.4, or ArgoUML, but in a sequence diagram, I want to show an object calling a method in its own class, ie calling a sub-procedure.

If I drag from the object to itself, nothing happens :-(

Thanks,
Ant

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to drag away, click, drag down, click, drag back to the original lifeline (ie make a U shape instead of a V shape or single line).  It seems like more work than should be necessary, but it does work.

This works in 0.30.2.  Not sure if it used to work differently (as Jordi's comment implies).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have problems with that. If you point the message arrow to the object column itself it correctly draws a reflexive message.

Comment: I'm using ArgoUML 0.30.2...  I have an object "/A:a", and it has the object column drawn below it.  I click either new call action, or new send action, and then click on the object column, drag away, and then drag back.  Nothing happens - the line disappears :-(

Comment: I´ve tried with the ¨Launch via web java start" version and indeed the line disappears. I was using an older version at home.

Answer (score 0):

Have around 10 grid line distance between the two life line. Now select the New Create Action and put the cursor on life line where you want the self call. Now drag away around 3 gridlines and click from same point drag downward click and drag backward up to the same life line where you stared. Thats all done!!